# java designing open closed principle in real life

Tags: java

Open closed principle says that use abstraction/strategy design pattern so that we dont need to change existing code and I understood that perfectly. When I see examples, it seems very easy. But in real life, there will be lot of domain objects and if we use Open closed principle, I will end up with thousands of classes.

My question is, do people follow this for big projects and create so many classes?

Also I am confused if all the business logic goes to domain objects, what is the logic people write in service classes (By service classes, I mean classes in service layer(web->service->dao). I apologize for silly questions but I am curious what is the standard way of designing in complex big projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are certainly not silly questions, let me try to answer them for you as best I can.

Regarding open-close principle, it's not related to specific design pattern or another, but rather to the general concept that classes should be open for extension and closed for modification.

The number of classes you have in a project should not intimidate you. Unfortunately, I have worked in companies where many classes were considered a bad thing ("hard to follow the code ...", "too big a knowledge base ...", and other ridiculous ideas like these).

The fact of the matter is, when you have few classes, chances are they are large classes, since all that business logic has to go somewhere, right ? This usually (pretty much always) means that each of your classes is doing a lot of stuff. Of course, by doing so much in each class, you're breaking the Single Responsibility Principle (aka SRP, another very important OOP principle) which makes the system much harder to maintain, and the code base much harder to understand.

Regarding what's the situation in real life, there's no one answer. I've had the opportunity to work for companies that really care about object oriented principles and enforce them rigorously (good !), and also for companies that were still stuck in the procedural coding style (not so good ...). All of these companies were profitable, delivered to customers, etc. The difference was that in the latter type of companies, it was much harder to understand the code as a new (or even a seasoned) employee, and it was a lot harder to change it (not to mention test it).

Regarding your other question about service layer implementation, I can attest from my own experience that usually the service layer itself is very thin. In general the classes implementing the service layer interfaces use one or more business objects inside to do the job, basically resulting in very short and coherent methods (good !). This is also a good example of an OOP principle, this time Inversion-of-Control (aka IoC), since a good practice in service layer implementations is to have all the business objects injected to it, rather than to create them in the constructor.

Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience. That clear lot of things. Can you please explain what do u mean by "service layer it self is very thin". Generally people say business logic goes in service layer and some ppl say in domain objects. I am confused. :(

Comment: Well, domain objects are pretty synonymous to business objects. What I mean by "thin" is that the majority of the work gets done by business/domain objects, which are used by the service layer to implement the service. Thus, the service layer just "seams" together the functionality oh the business objects.